Whats the chance this contains asbestos?
Garage sheathing. Any chance this would be suspicious for asbestos? I'm thinking no, but just kinda getting some other visual opinions.
https://imgur.com/a/zg73HaU
https://imgur.com/a/eP6clTb

The best answer you get online is Yes, No, Maybe.  It has to be tested to be sure.  Age does help some, post 90s is less likely than 40s.

visual opinions are worth zero in this case

Fiber-cement made with asbestos looks just like fiber-cement made with other fibers. Lab test is the only way. Shop around calmly and skeptically, there are those who prey upon people with asbestos panic and charge 6 times the going rate. Date of construction and location on the planet also matter.
